# GitLab: deleted a user and recreating same user give error "Username has already been taken Username already exists"

Tags: gitlab, createuser, gitlab-omnibus

I'm using GitLab Community Edition 8.2.2

What's the correct way to delete a user if you want to recreate it?

In my case the user wanted to swap the  userid and name fields but keep his email address unchanged.  When I try to add the user, after already deleting him.
I get the error:

> "Username has already been taken Username already exists" even though
>   the user does not exists.

Comment: I'd say this is probably related to cache. The username you're trying to create is already stored somewhere, or in a database or in the cache.

Comment: Yes, I thought so too, so I did the following to flush the cache.
 "sudo gitlab-rake cache:clear" but that did not solve the problem

Comment: Have you tried this: `DELETE /users/:id` ? And/or `DELETE /user/keys/:id` ? It's on GL docs.

Comment: There's also `cd /home/git/gitlab` -> `sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake cache:clear RAILS_ENV=production`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.  use of the API worked.  It allowed me to query all the users, and I identified that there was another user using the same id, thus that was the issue with being able to add the new user.  For those wanting to see the api called, its not that obvious within the GitLab documentation.  I used:

curl "http://yourgitserver.com/api/v3/users?private_token=DUTnxN7youprivatetokenvalueDUTnxN7"